# Удаление trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'))

Tags: php

Попробовал так удалить пробел, не вышло, зашел в документацию и...

> [**Замечание:**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-notes)
>
> Может показаться странным, что результатом вызова
>   `trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'));` не является пустая строка. Причина
>   том, что `&nbsp;` преобразуется не в символ с ASCII-кодом 32 (который
>   удаляется функцией `trim()`),а в символ с ASCII-кодом 160 (0xa0) в
>   принимаемой по умолчанию кодировке ISO-8859-1.

Я подумал, а что если проверить какой символ выведет функция

`ord(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'))`

В надежде получить код символа 160, я получил 194...

Как? И самое забавное что `chr(194)` - битый символ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В надежде получить код символа 160, я получил 194...
>
> Как? И самое забавное что chr(194) - битый символ

Вы получили не битый символ, а первый байт символа *Неразрывный пробел* из UTF-8, так как:

1. функция `ord()` работает с однобайтными символами
2. Неразрывный пробел в UTF-8 представлен байтами: `194` `160`

```
<?php
function ordutf8($string, &$offset) {
    $code = ord(substr($string, $offset,1));
    if ($code >= 128) {        //otherwise 0xxxxxxx
        if ($code < 224) $bytesnumber = 2;                //110xxxxx
        else if ($code < 240) $bytesnumber = 3;        //1110xxxx
        else if ($code < 248) $bytesnumber = 4;    //11110xxx
        $codetemp = $code - 192 - ($bytesnumber > 2 ? 32 : 0) - ($bytesnumber > 3 ? 16 : 0);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $bytesnumber; $i++) {
            $offset ++;
            $code2 = ord(substr($string, $offset, 1)) - 128;        //10xxxxxx
            $codetemp = $codetemp*64 + $code2;
        }
        $code = $codetemp;
    }
    $offset += 1;
    if ($offset >= strlen($string)) $offset = -1;
    return $code;
}

$offset = 0;
var_dump(ordutf8(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'), $offset));
```

Результат

```
int 160
```

PHP 5.4.31 - 7.0.4

Функция взята из [мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ord.php#109812)

Comment: А в самом php нет функций (ord, chr) для работы с мультибайтовыми кодировками?

Comment: Нет. И функция `trim()` может работать не правильно с UTF-8, если вы укажите во втором параметре не однобайтный символ. P.S. chr UTF-8 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chr.php#88611

Comment: Спасибо, за хорошее объяснение пойду обмозгую принцип работы данных функций

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, у Вас `PHP 5.6` и старше.
Тогда параметр `encoding` берётся из конфигурации `default_charset`.
С указанной версии пыха эта настройка по дефолту [настроена на `UTF-8`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset), который, действительно, возвратит `194`.
Если установить ту кодировку, что в замечании, то всё работает:

```
var_dump(ord(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;', ENT_HTML5, 'ISO-8859-1'))); // int(160)
```

*PHP 7.1*

Comment: хмм, а почему мне тогда возврщает битый символ по коду 194?

Comment: @MaximPro, потому что Вы используете `UTF-8`, который, видимо, возвращает символ по коду `194`. Разные кодировки такие разные :)

Comment: я чутка порылся в сети и нашел `nbsp;` он представлен в utf-8 как 2 кода `c2 a0 - 194 160`